# Beginner: Argument 'CropsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined (angularjs)(firebase)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem with Angular JS controllers and routing..

stations.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="StationsCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-5" ng-show="addFormShow">
        <h3>Add Stations</h3>
        <form ng-submit="addStation()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Station Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Station Name" ng-model="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" ng-model="date"><span ng-bind="date"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rainfall</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="rainfall">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3>Stations</h3>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Station</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Rainfall</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="station in stations | filter:search ">
                    <td>{{ station.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ station.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ station.rainfall }}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="removeStation(station)">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="showEditForm(station)">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>



    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="">
            <select ng-options="station.name for station in stations" ng-model="selectOption" class="form-control"></select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <label for="">Rainfall: </label>{{ station.rainfall }} Rainfall:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ selectOption.rainfall }}" value="{{ selectOption.rainfall }}" ngmodel="selectedRain">
            </div>
            <pre>{{selectOption | json}}</pre>
            <h1>{{ selectOption.name }}</h1>
        </form>
    </div>




    <div class="col-md-5" ng-show="editFormShow">
        <h3>Edit Station</h3>
        <form ng-submit="editStation()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Station Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Station Name" ng-model="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" ng-model="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rainfall</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="rainfall">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>
<hr>
<div class="row" ng-controller="CropsCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-5" ng-show="addFormShow">
        <h3>Add Crops</h3>
        <form ng-submit="addCrop()">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Crop Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Crop Name" ng-model="cname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Planting Emergence</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="plantingEmeregence">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3>Crops</h3>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Crop</th>
                    <th>Planting Emergence</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="crop in crops | filter:search ">
                    <td>{{ station.cname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ station.plantingEmergence }}</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="removeStation(station)">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="showEditForm(station)">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="">
            <select ng-options="station.name for station in stations" ng-model="selectOption1" class="form-control"></select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <label for="">Planting Emergence: </label>{{ crop.plantingEmergence }} Planting Emergence:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ crop.plantingEmergence }}" value="{{ crop.plantingEmergence }}" ngmodel="selectedPE">
            </div>
            <pre>{{selectOption1 | json}}</pre>
            <h1>{{ selectOption1.name }}</h1>
        </form>
    </div>




    <div class="col-md-5" ng-show="editFormShow">
        <h3>Edit Station</h3>
        <form ng-submit="editStation()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Station Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Station Name" ng-model="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" ng-model="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rainfall</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="rainfall">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

- crops.js

  ```
  angular.module('myApp.crops', ['ngRoute','firebase'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'stations/stations.html',
         controller: 'CropsCtrl'
       });
     }])
    .controller('CropsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray',function($scope,$firebaseArray) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();

  $scope.crops = $firebaseArray(ref);
  $scope.addFormShow = true;
  $scope.editFormShow = false;

  $scope.showEditForm = function(crop){
      $scope.addFormShow = false;
      $scope.editFormShow = true;

      $scope.id = crop.$id;
      $scope.name = crop.name;
      $scope.plantingEmergence = crop.plantingEmergence;
      //$scope.rainfall = crop.rainfall;

  }


  $scope.addCrop = function(){
      console.log("adding Crop");

      $scope.crops.$add({
          name : $scope.name,
          plantingEmergence : $scope.plantingEmergence,
      }).then(function(ref){
          var id =ref.key;
          console.log("added stations" +id);

          $scope.name = '';
          $scope.plantingEmergence = '';
      });
  }

  $scope.removeCrop = function(crop){
      $scope.crops.$remove(crop);
  }

  $scope.editCrop = function(){
      var id = $scope.id;

      var record = $scope.crops.$getRecord(id);

      record.name = $scope.name;
      record.plantingEmergence = $scope.plantingEmergence;

      //save
      $scope.crops.$save(record).then(function(ref){
          console.log(ref.key);
      });

      $scope.name = '';
      $scope.plantingEmergence = '';
  }
  }]);
  ```
- stations.js

  ```
    'use strict';


    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCmLUPbeZ-ANNJcSXB2SbZsNcWa3CQtrwg",
      authDomain: "stations-afb5a.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://stations-afb5a.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "stations-afb5a.appspot.com",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);


  angular.module('myApp.stations', ['ngRoute','firebase'])
  //angular.module('stationsApp', ['firebase']);

  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'stations/stations.html',
      controller: 'StationsCtrl'
    });
  }])

  .controller('StationsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray',function($scope,$firebaseArray) {
      var ref = firebase.database().ref();

      $scope.stations = $firebaseArray(ref);
      $scope.crops = $firebaseArray(ref);
      $scope.addFormShow = true;
      $scope.editFormShow = false;

      $scope.showEditForm = function(station){
          $scope.addFormShow = false;
          $scope.editFormShow = true;

          $scope.id = station.$id;
          $scope.name = station.name;
          $scope.date = station.date;
          $scope.rainfall = station.rainfall;

      }

      $scope.ninja = ['when','where','how','ping'];


      $scope.addStation = function(){
          console.log("adding Station");

          $scope.stations.$add({
              name : $scope.name,
              date : $scope.date,
              rainfall : $scope.rainfall,
          }).then(function(ref){
              var id =ref.key;
              console.log("added stations" +id);

              $scope.name = '';
              $scope.date = '';
              $scope.rainfall = '';
          });
      }

      $scope.removeStation = function(station){
          $scope.stations.$remove(station);
      }

      $scope.editStation = function(){
          var id = $scope.id;

          var record = $scope.stations.$getRecord(id);

          record.name = $scope.name;
          record.dat = $scope.date;
          record.rainfall = $scope.rainfall;

          //save
          $scope.stations.$save(record).then(function(ref){
              console.log(ref.key);
          });

          $scope.name = '';
          $scope.date = '';
          $scope.rainfall = '';
      }

  }]);
  ```

Comment: This specific controller doesn't appear to hang off of what you set for your `ng-app` attribute. Where do you declare your app in your html file?

Comment: A couple of comments: (1) the use of `$` to prefix your own variables/objects/functions is a very, **VERY** bad idea. Not that it would cause the code to stop working, but will make life miserable for any developer trying to read and understand your code. (2) the error message indicates that you have a syntactic error within the definition of your `CropsCtrl` controller. Best way to debug is by commenting out code till the error disappears, and uncomment part by part till you got it back. Then, you will be able to pin-point to the statement that generates the error.